# Fill an array, symmetric with respect to its centre

Tags: random, list-manipulation, piecewise

I want to create an array that must be symmetric with respect to the centre of it, as in the following example:

```
0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

but, instead of having such simple numbers in the array, I need to fill the array by extracting the i-th number from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance equal to a function of the index i.
I have tried to use `Piecewise`, at least to fill the first half of the array, but I don't know how to fill the other half:

```
KfieldREAL[k_] := Piecewise[{{0, k == 0},
     {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], 
     0 < k <= n/2}, (*missing part here*)
```

How can I create an array like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating the left half and using its image for the right half.

```
sigma = .25; L = 300; mu = 1; n = 1000;

left = Table[{k,RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]]}, {k, n/2}];

right = Reverse[left] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y}; (*imaging*)
full = Join[Most[left], right];
ListPlot[full, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

> Adding extra elements

Let say you want to put the element `x1` [say, (0,0)] at the beginning or end. You can simply put it during the `Join`.

```
x1={0,0.0}; x2={n+1,0.0}; (*first and last element in (k,f(k)) format*)
full=Join[{x1},Most[left], right,{x2}];
```

Note that when using join, you don't use a single element `x1`, rather a list containing a single element `{x1}`.

for `n=8` it looks like

$
\begin{array}{l l}
 0 & 0.00000 \\
 1 & 1.47757 \\
 2 & 2.29881 \\
 3 & 1.46615 \\
 4 & 1.34819 \\
 5 & 1.46615 \\
 6 & 2.29881 \\
 7 & 1.47757 \\
 9 & 0.00000 \\
\end{array}
$

And your list now has `n+1` element. This is because the axis of reflection goes through `4`. If you want even number of element then use `n+1` for `right` and omit `Most` in `final`.

```
right = Reverse[left] /. {x_, y_} -> {n + 1 - x, y};
full = Join[left, right];
```

And the result for `n=8` after adding the zeros

```
x1 = {0, 0.0}; x2 = {n + 1, 0.0};
full = Join[{x1}, left, right, {x2}];
```

$
\begin{array}{ll}
 0 & 0.00000 \\
 1 & 0.380134 \\
 2 & 1.48306 \\
 3 & 0.509712 \\
 4 & 1.76137 \\ \hline
 5 & 1.76137 \\
 6 & 0.509712 \\
 7 & 1.48306 \\
 8 & 0.380134 \\
 9 & 0.00000 \\
\end{array}
$

Now `4` and `5` has same element and number of elements in your final list iss `n+2`.

Comment: You could also use `full = ArrayPad[left, n/2-1, "Reflected"]`.

Comment: Thanks @Pickett. I didn't know about that syntax.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The method described in @Sumit 's answer works very well, I just need to add the first element, which is 0 (because that's what the theory imposes). How can I do that? I have tried using Join, but I did not succeed in adding a first element, set to 0.

Comment: Just a wild guess for adding the leading 0: `Join[{0},(a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], i]), 
   Drop[Reverse[a], 1]]` Note the curly braces around the zero in the `Join` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[kfR]
kfR[mu_: 0, sigma_: 1, L_: 100] := With[{m = Array[
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2 Pi # sigma/L)^2]]] &, Ceiling[#/2]]},
   Prepend[m[[MapThread[Min, {Range[#], Reverse@Range[#]}]]], 0]] &

MatrixPlot[{kfR[][10]}, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> 800,
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{#, #-1} & /@ Range[11], {#, #-1} & /@ Range[11]}}]
```

[image]

Using `MultinormalDistribution` instead of `NormalDistribution`:

```
ClearAll[kfR2]
kfR2[mu_: 0, sigma_: 1, L_: 100] := With[{m = ConstantArray[mu, Ceiling[#/2]], 
  s = DiagonalMatrix[Exp[-(2*Pi*Range[Ceiling[#/2]]*sigma/L)^2]], 
  ind = MapThread[Min, {Range[#], Reverse@Range[#]}]}, 
 Prepend[RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[m, s]][[ind]], 0]] &;

Panel[Column[MatrixPlot[{aa = (kfR2[][#])}, AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
     ImageSize -> 800, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, None},
       {rng = ({#, # - 1} & /@ Range[# + 1]), rng},
     Epilog -> (MapIndexed[Style[Text[Round[#, .2], {First[#2] - 1/2, 1/2}],
         "Panel", 18, Bold, Background -> Transparent] &, aa])] & /@ 
    {5, 6, 11, 12}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not what I need, because you are changing only the variance of the distribution from which the numbers are extracted in the second half of the array. I need the numbers to be an exact duplicate of the first half, with the symmetry described in my question before

Comment: @user, i see.. I will post a fixed version,

Answer (score 0):

```
myMatrix[i_, j_] := 
 Table[Join[(a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], i]), 
   Drop[Reverse[a], 1]], {j}]

 ListPlot[myMatrix[10, 10], Joined -> True]
```

[image]